# How do i set up laravel as an backend api for nuxtjs

Tags: laravel, api, nuxt.js

I've starterd working on a project based of a template i found on github. This template includes laravel, nuxtjs and vuetify. In this template laravel serves as a backend api for my nuxtjs project; Which is what i need.

***The github repo: https://github.com/BakayYank/laravel-nuxt-vuetify***

But what i dont like about this template is that the package.json file is filled with dependencies of which i dont know what they do or even if i need them.

I want to make my own project with laravel and nuxt but i don't know how to make laravel an api or how to send data to this api.

If anyone could help me understand or provide me a source that would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This course teaches that beautifully if you are willing to pay for a month (It's totally worth it!). [Laravel Api/NUXT Frontend Course](https://codecourse.com/courses/build-an-e-commerce-platform)

Otherwise, you would build the laravel app as normal but don't use blade views. Then in NUXT send data using ajax requests. If you have any other questions let me know! I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! What i would like to know is in which files and how do i send data with ajax request? I am not very familiar with ajax... Is there maybe any info you can give me on how this works or maybe provide a link with info because i really dont know where to start... Thanks!